# What does "Visual Studio Code" setup uses?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I recently installed Microsoft new "Visual Studio Code" on Windows. The entire setup was quick and nice. What technology is that? Is it clickonce? It was smooth and quick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's using [Squirrel](https://github.com/Squirrel/Squirrel.Windows)  to create a self extracting zip archive containing a nuget package.  Squirrel only supports per-user installation and because of that it doesn't impress me.

Enterprises want per-machine installations with auto-update disabled so that change can be centrally managed.  Technologies like Click Once and Squirrel just ignore this and do limited things in the per-user context with auto updates enabled.   Two different animals.